# syntax error for command: "GRANT EXECUTE ON USERNAME.PKG.PROCEDURE TO OTHERUSER;"

Tags: oracle

I want to grant execute permission to user B so that it can execute a packaged procedure belonging to user A.

```
procedure name = PKGNAME.PROCEDURENAME
user = USERA
```

I am trying below command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON USERA.PKGNAME.PROCEDURENAME TO USERB;
```

But it gives me error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00905: missing keyword

is there a syntax problem ? I used this link :
[Granting Rights on Stored Procedure to another user of Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305323/granting-rights-on-stored-procedure-to-another-user-of-oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't grant permissions on a procedure which is within a package, either grant permissions to the entire package or move the procedure outside of the package so it's a stand alone one and then grant permission

so either

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON USERA.PKGNAME TO USERB;
```

or

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON USERA.PROCEDURENAME TO USERB;
```

Comment: This answer did not help my problem. I have a procedure outside a package and the suggested `grant` statement does not work. I have the same error as the OP.