# Oracle schema level privileges

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema, privileges

I have created one user in my oracle database. I have given read-only access to 2-3 schemas.

But I also want to grant access to those schemas with the ability to run packages and procedures.

How can I do that?

Granted read-only access to those schemas.

Comment: I am not sure quite what you are asking for.  Do you just want to `grant execute on <<package>> to <<user>>`?  Or is that not what you want for some reason?

Comment: Please check below [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305323/granting-rights-on-stored-procedure-to-another-user-of-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON b.procedure_name TO a
```

Please check your query below

[Granting Rights on Stored Procedure to another user of Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305323/granting-rights-on-stored-procedure-to-another-user-of-oracle)